# How to convert *const u8 with length to &str without reallocation?

Tags: rust

I am looking for the best way (hopefully zero cost) to achieve this:

```rust
fn to_str(str: *const u8, len: usize) -> Option<&str>;
```

`len` is the length of a string that may or may not be null-terminated and `str` is a pointer to that string.

I do not want to take ownership of the string and just need to pass it around as `&str`.

Comment: If you check the signature of the function, you can see that I do not want ownership. Ownership is not zero cost and most of the time when we are working with a buffer of u8 that is a pointer to a character owned by a C/C++ code, in this particular case, it is the linux kernel, are code should not slow the system by making unnecessary copies of data that is readily available.

Comment: Ok, I misread the question as wanting to take ownership. However, note that by "taking ownership" I didn't mean "make a copy"! There are ways of taking ownership without copying - being owner just means calling `free()` in the destructor.

Comment: Note however that if the string is allocated by C, it must be also destoyed by C. That is, indeed, by calling `free`, not by letting the Rust `String` or `Vec` get their `Drop` implementation called.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Seems I already had the answer:

```rust
#[inline]
#[allow(clippy::not_unsafe_ptr_arg_deref)]
pub fn from_char_buff<'a>(ptr: *const u8, len: size_t) -> Option<&'a str> {
/// SAFETY: We need to make sure that pointer is not null.
    if ptr.is_null() {
        None
    } else {
        unsafe {
            let buff = std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len as usize);
/// SAFETY: Using the standard from_utf8 function, we ensure that the sequence is a valid string or NONE. 
/// In case of invalid sequence of strings the function returns None.
/// Considering that the pointer is also not null there is no scenario under which the return value of this function won't be a proper string.
/// There is no chance for an undefined behaviour.
/// Therefor the return value of this function is both safe and sound.
// As a consequence not_unsafe_ptr_arg_deref warning is not relevant and has to be supressed.
            std::str::from_utf8(buff).ok()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not disable [the lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#not_unsafe_ptr_arg_deref). The function ought to be `unsafe` since there's no way to know if `ptr` is valid.

Comment: This function can be safe if and only if it is private and every place where it is used guarantees the `ptr` to point on `len` initialized bytes. Otherwise, it must be unsafe, as calling it with dangling non-null pointer or with pointer to the smaller allocation is insta-UB.

Comment: @Cerberus This is not my code, that is why I asked, I found this in a popular crate. Can you provide an alternative that is safe and I will accept your response and notify the crate maintainer of the serious mistake?

Comment: Well, there's not really safe alternative, since it's impossible in general to know what the pointer points to, aside from looking through the code manually. What crate are you talking about?

Comment: @Cerberus Even if the function is private, it should stlil be marked unsafe because it has a safety invariant that the caller is required to uphold.

Comment: Well, in this case it's at least a "should" and not "must". I'd agree that it'd be better to make it unsafe anyway, however.

Comment: @user4815162342  can you make this safe, please? The actual question is not answered yet.

Comment: @Reza I think there is a misunderstanding here between the different meanings of "safe" and "sound". There is one question of whether the function can be implemented without the use of `unsafe`. (It can't, because it accepts a raw pointer.) The other question is whether the function should be _marked_ as unsafe - some functions use unsafe _internally_, but expose a safe interface. (If they do so correctly, we call their implementation _sound_.) I argue that this function can't have a safe interface, as long as it's required to accept a raw pointer.

Comment: @user4815162342 so you agree that this function is sound yet you believe it needs to be flagged unsafe? all pointers are unsafe yet we have many crates that interact with C function and the public-facing APIs are considered safe. At what point a developer may decide that adding an unsafe keyword to this function is just going to force us to add an unnecessary unsafe wrapper at the call site without doing anything extra to make the call safer? Can you really think of any benefit of adding an unsafe keyword here?

Comment: @Reza The fact that the caller needs to uphold a safety invariant manually (ensure a non-null valid pointer, otherwise you get undefined behavior) is what requires this function to be marked unsafe. Unfortunately the function is probably also unsound because it has a separate issue with lifetime of the returned string. I'm writing an answer that addresses that.

Comment: @john-kugelman The job of std::str::from_utf8(buff).ok() to make sure that this is a valid sequence of characters.

Comment: @Reza Your checks do not cover all requirements to safely dereference a pointer: 1) that it points to a allocated memory region, 2) that it does not alias with with an existing mutable reference, 3) the lifetime does not exceed the life of the source. There is no way to ensure these cases from within the function, so you should mark it as unsafe and indicate as such in the function's documentation for the user to guarantee. In the context of a FFI layer, a function like this would still be unsafe, but you can typically craft a safe wrapper around it by having the library make these guarantees.

Comment: @kmdreko we are sending back a reference a &str. It is a borrowed reference. The lifetime of such is static. That is 99% of all FFI code including all system calls in Rust. I suggest you just pick a random sys caret, for instance, nix gethostname and see how a borrowed reference to the outside world is not only common but is a necessity for Rust to have any real value communicating with the OS in a proficient way.

Comment: You still don't know that `ptr` is valid, and there's no way to check if it is. It's not enough to check for null. The user could call `from_char_buff(NonNull::dangling().as_ptr(), 1)`. [`dangling`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.dangling) returns a pointer that isn't null, yet also isn't valid and is illegal to dereference.

Comment: @john-kugelman let's say you changed the signature of the function to unsafe. passing a dangling reference is going to end up with "SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference". This has nothing to do with the signature of the function, does it? Can you show us how changing the signature to unsafe, could avoid SIGSEGV? Doesn't the other answer, also get SIGSEGV? (answer: it does)

Comment: Marking the function `unsafe` doesn't fix anything, it doesn't prevent a crash. That's not the purpose of it. What it does do is force the caller to add an `unsafe` block, which should be their cue to go read your documentation so they can see what requirements they're supposed to satisfy to make the call safe. You can say, "you must pass a valid, non-null pointer," and then it's the caller's responsibility to do that...

Comment: ...However, if you omit `unsafe`, then callers are *not* required to read your documentation. One of Rust's fundamental tenets is that people who write safe Rust without any `unsafe` blocks must *never* be able to violate memory safety. You are *not* supposed to write safe functions that will do unsafe things like dereference an invalid pointer if the caller doesn't read the docs carefully. Functions like that must always be marked `unsafe`.

Comment: I am not going to continue with this. This is now a straw man argument and I have better things to do than trying to point out the fallacy that not only does the function checks for null pointers at no point I claimed that it is the responsibility of the caller to make sure it is not null. The rust idiom on how to comment safe wrappers is also a well-known practice. You don't mark a function unsafe just so that the people read the documents.

Answer (score 6):

Rust's reference such as `&str` is associated with a *lifetime*. This lifetime is attached to the value that owns the underlying data, typically a container like `String`, `Vec` or array. So to get a valid `&str` you need an *owner*. You don't want to take ownership of the data because you don't want to copy it. However, owning doesn't imply copying, it just means taking exclusive responsibility for mutating and destroying the data.

To own data represented by a pointer coming from C's `malloc()` without copying the data, you could wrap the pointer:

```
pub struct MyString {
    data: *const u8,
    length: usize,
}

impl MyString {
    // safety: data must point to nul-terminated memory allocated with malloc()
    pub unsafe fn new(data: *const u8, length: usize) -> MyString {
        // Note: no reallocation happens here, we use `str::from_utf8()` only to
        // check whether the pointer contains valid UTF-8.
        // If panic is unacceptable, the constructor can return a `Result`
        if std::str::from_utf8(std::slice::from_raw_parts(data, length)).is_err() {
            panic!("invalid utf-8")
        }
        MyString { data, length }
    }

    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe {
            // from_utf8_unchecked is sound because we checked in the constructor
            std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.data, self.length))
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for MyString {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            libc::free(self.data as *mut _);
        }
    }
}
```

This only requires unsafe when constructing the wrapper with `MyString::new()` because it takes a raw pointer whose validity cannot be checked at compile time. Afterwards the wrapper gives you the `&str` that you can pass around without any unsafe:

```
fn main() {
    let raw_str = unsafe { libc::strdup(b"foo\0".as_ptr() as _) as *const u8 };
    let s = unsafe { MyString::new(raw_str, 3) };
    // from here on, it's all-safe code
    let slice = s.as_str();  // now you get a slice to pass around
    assert_eq!(slice, "foo");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1984252dd62592e1ad14a67a865f5d76)

If you don't want `MyString` to deallocate the data, then you can simply delete the `Drop` implementation. In either case, `new()` has a safety invariant that the data must not be deallocated while `MyString` is live.

One final difference between C strings and Rust `&str` is that Rust strings are guaranteed to be UTF-8, and creating non-UTF-8 strings (which can only be done in unsafe code) constitutes [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html). This is why either `MyString::new()` or `MyString::as_str()` need to verify that the string contains valid UTF-8. Putting the check in `new()` ensures the check is done at most once. You can remove the check, but then `new()` gets another safety invariant, one that is unlikely to be respected by C code that creates strings.

To represent arbitrary binary data, you can use `&[u8]` instead of `&str`, or use a crate like [bstr](https://docs.rs/bstr/latest/bstr/) that gives you "byte strings" with all the conveniences of `&str` but without requiring UTF-8 requirement.

Comment: Why are you calculating the length while the length is what the content signature already provides? Also, strdup creates a brand new string by allocating new memory, Also checking every single character to make sure they pass utf8 requirements is an extra computational cost. Am I missing something here? How is your answer zero costs and without new allocation? What makes your code any better than the official CString if we didn't had the requirement for zero allocation and zero cost?

Comment: @Reza Good point about length, I've now edited the answer to accept it. UTF-8 is a requirement of `&str`, as mentioned in the answer, and you can remove it, but only if you have a guarantee that the data is UTF-8 (which sounds unlikely for Linux). As for `strdup()`, it's just an example - I needed some way to procure a malloced C string, and `strdup()` is a quick way to do it in a demo.

Comment: *How is your answer zero costs and without new allocation?* - `MyString` doesn't allocate, it uses the existing allocation and only stores the pointer. (The `MyString` struct is itself stack-allocated.) It's different from `CString` because CString actually allocates and, when constructed, always creates a fresh copy of the data. The only cost of using `MyString` is the UTF-8 check, but that's a requirement of `&str`, so it comes with the territory.

Comment: I can see there are 2 difference between your code and the code that you rejected. One is that the in your code you panic when the sequence is not a valid utf8 while the one you didn't like sends back None which is the recommended way. Also your code uses from_utf8_unchecked which does not even check to make sure the sequence is valid. In other words your code, panics, mine sends back None, your code sends back the result of from_utf8_unchecked which is unsound and unsafe as safe, mine sends back a sound result as safe. Your code is simply dangerous. I suggest you delete it.

Comment: @Reza It's trivial to change the panic to a result of `None` or `Err`, and I mention that in the answer. `from_utf8_unchecked` is sound because the data was already checked in the constructor. The difference between this answer and yours is that this one correctly handles lifetimes and actually verifies that the data is UTF-8. The assertion that this code is somehow "dangerous" is both unjustified and untrue, and if it's meant as provocation, it is unwarranted because I genuinely tried to help you. I doubt you'll get a better answer, given the constraints.

Comment: First of all it is not trivial to change panic to none. We do not throw panic around in Rust. Secondly based on Rust documentation from_utf8_unchecked the function does not check for utf8 and in case of invalid ut8 sequence the result is undefined and violated source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html. Finally your code "safe "public" function only calls the above function and assumes it is safe, You were upset that my code that actually checks for both null and utf8 is unsafe while your code doesn't do either.

Comment: As someone who has been coding for 30 years, I don't provocate. I just get disappointed with obvious errors by someone who is fully aware of what he is doing just to get a few meaningless votes. In your class, the method you have as safe is more dangerous than the one you have flagged as UNsafe. You do more check in your unsafe code and none in your safe code.

Comment: @Reza *First of all it is not trivial to change panic to none. We do not throw panic around in Rust* - I meant change in the implementation of the API, not in its usage. *Secondly based on Rust documentation from_utf8_unchecked* - This is again a misunderstanding - the check is unnecessary in `MyString::as_str()` because it was already performed in `MyString::new()`. As for your code, it accepted a raw pointer (and dereferenced it) in a function marked as **safe**. On the other hand, `MyString::new()` is marked as unsafe, with the safety contract documented. That is the difference.

Comment: Not here to argue, my comments are here yours are here, People decide which approach they want to take.

Comment: @Reza There is no arguing, I honestly addressed your concerns about my code. I've also coded for some decades and trust me that I didn't write the answer to get the votes, but to actually help you. If you don't see it (or look at it differently) and my arguments don't reach you, I guess I can't change your mind.

Comment: if we mix your first and second function, which is what you now say is the way to do, your code is  std::str::from_utf8 (checked) with Option as result rather than panic.  from_utf8 already checks for utf8 and it converts to str is a single function maintained by rust core.rather than 8 lines of code. There is absolutely nothing else in your code to make it safer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Reza *There is absolutely nothing else in your code to make it safer. Am I missing something?* - Two things: that `MyString::new()` is marked unsafe with the safety contract clearly documented. The second is the lifetime issue - `MyString::as_str()` returns the `&str` with the lifetime of `MyStr` (which takes ownership of the data without copying it, but with freeing it in `Drop`). OTOH `from_char_buff()` can be adapted to any lifetime whatsoever, which means the caller has to ensure that `&str` doesn't outlive the data behind the pointer - which is why it should be marked unsafe.